# How to show the logs generated from getStatic functions in Next.js in production mode (and Vercel)?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I wrote some `console.log()` in my getStaticProps functions but I cannot find the logs anywhere, I need that to fix some pages static generation bugs, so where can I find them or store them?

I use Vercel as a hosting service.

Comment: I'd recommend a read through [Vercel Logs](https://vercel.com/docs/logs) documentation. The `getStaticProps` logs should be available under Build logs.

Comment: @juliomalves yea ofc, but I'm talking about the logs generated even after the build process...

Comment: [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) is called at build time to statically generate the pages. Are you using `revalidate` in `getStaticProps` by any chance? If so, then the logs would be in the Functions logs.

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps` calls at runtime are classed as serverless functions and can be found in the Vercel logs.  Navigate to your deployment in Vercel and select Logs. From the filters on the left select `Level = Error` and `Type = Serverless Function` and a suitable timeframe and you will see any errors thrown from your `getStaticProps` functions.